# Convert Yahoo Finance List to Dataframe

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib
import time
import sys
baseurl = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"
yql_bs_query = 'select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "YHOO" and startDate = "2009-09-11" and endDate = "2010-03-10"'
yql_bs_url = baseurl + urllib.parse.urlencode({'q':yql_bs_query}) + "&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback="
bs_json = pd.io.json.read_json(yql_bs_url)
bs_json.values
YHOO = bs_json.values.tolist()
```

Not able to convert this list in dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is converting to a DataFrame but the frame has only 1 column and 5 rows since the form of the JSON is:

```
{u'query': {u'count': 124,
        u'created': u'2017-01-26T05:44:52Z',
        u'diagnostics': {u'build-version': u'2.0.84',
...
```

You just need to download the JSON separately, index in to get the quote data, and then convert that to a DataFrame:

```
# same code as above here:
import pandas as pd
import urllib
import time
import sys
baseurl = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"
yql_bs_query = 'select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "YHOO" and startDate = "2009-09-11" and endDate = "2010-03-10"'
yql_bs_url = baseurl + urllib.parse.urlencode({'q':yql_bs_query}) + "&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback="

# now that you have the URL:
import requests

# download json data and convert to dict
data = requests.get(yql_bs_url).json()

# get quote data
quote = data["query"]["results"]["quote"]

# convert to dataframe
quote = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(quote)
```